# What is the pointer size in Jni on a 64bit architecture

Tags: java, java-native-interface, 64-bit

I'm developing a Java wrapper for a C++ project using Jni. 
As I'm having some trouble (null pointer exception), I'm investigating. 
I'm compiling my project on a x64 linux architecture using gcc and jdk-1.6. 
If I look at `jni_md.h` it seems to me that `jlong` is defined as `long long`. I would think that the correct size would be `long`. I just want to be sure that jlong is corectly defined.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JNI `jlong` is [defined as 64 bits](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.doc.htmlhttp://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.doc.html) (to match a Java `long`.)

A `long long` (in C99) is defined as **at least** 64 bits.

It cannot be a C `long`.  A C `long` is only defined as at least 32 bits.

Comment: Oh yes you are right, I was mixing up java long and c long.. thanks

Comment: @YannSagon: yes, and looking at my answer again, I see why.  I'll update to denote the languages I'm talking about.